# which Collection to use for one to many type of data ?

Tags: java, collections

I have following table structure :

table name : lookup

cloumns : appname, wfname , wfdir , sessname

so correspoding to a particular appname, wfname and wfdir , i have multiple sessname .

```
  app1,wf1,anydir,sess1
  app1,wf1,anydir,sess2
  app1,wf1,anydir,sess3
  app2,wf2,anydir2,sess1
  app2,wf2,anydir2,sess2
```

for some reason i cannot normalize the table . So what would be the best way to store this data coming from the lookup tabel. which collection should i use ?

What i have done is : 
Created an arryalist of each column and then i have stored these data . What would be the more efficient way for storing these type of data ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "storing" since this is gonna be held in memory only. Why do you want to load an entire table to memory? If for some reason you have to... maybe use arrays inside an `ArrayList`? `ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();`

Comment: I have 4 tables and after getting these columns from lookup table i have to perform operations on other table , like compare if  value from a particular column of lookup is present in other table .if yes then insert some data into that table. That's why i need to store the entire data from table into objects.

Comment: Please clarify: Does your table need three different keys, or a key that combines three different values? If the latter, my answer is going in the right direction. If the former, you just need three separate hashtables pointing at the same set of data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested options for one to many:

1) `Map` whose values are `Set`s. 
2) Apache's `MultiMap` class, which encapsulate that concept.

But it sounds like you actually want to go the other way. The easiest way to do that would be to implement a `Comparable` object which holds the three individual keys you want to use and implements `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` in terms of them, and use that as the `Map`'s key.

Comment: How can i achieve it using map ? Because map is key value pair and i have appname, wfname , wfdir as the key and sessname as value. How can i have 3 keys for a single value ?

Comment: @user3436156: See revised answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit , i am not understanding what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Row class

```
class Row {
   String appname;
   String wfname;
   String wfdir;
   String sessname ;
 ...
```

and use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve result set order